OAuth 2.0 Client IDs - Warning Icons Meaning
What does this warning icon mean beside my OAuth permissions. I have applied for, gone through Google review successfully for sensitive scripes, and been approved for public use of these permissions.
I cannot determine what this icon means nor see what is the required action to take.


Can you hover over the warning symbol?

When I hover I get "This automatically generated OAuth client ID is required for your project. It can't be modified."

Does that answer your question?

If that's all it means then great, it just seems like that doesn't warrant a scary warning icon.

I have high confidence that that's what that means. Take that however you want!
